# How to make the text look like that in LateX

Tags: latex

I need to make the line on the picture the exact same as in the image.
[How it has to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BTn6.png)

And this is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \captionof{table}{} \label{tab:table 1}
    %I think that the line must be here
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c||c|}
            \hline
            Level & Trial & Mod. & Time & Prop. & Tot.\\
            \hline
            2 & 478 & 2 & 1h 19m & 3/5 & 16\\
            3 & 408 & 1 & 1h 04m & 2/5 & 12\\
            4 & 400 & 2 & 1h 00m & 3/5 & 14\\
            5 & 7531 & 3 & 17h 52m & 2/5 & 6\\
            6 & 402 & 1 & 0h 50m & 3/5 & 11\\
            \hline
            av. & 1843 & 1.6 & 4h 25m & 2.4/5 & 11.8\\
            av2 & 422 & 1.5 & 1h 3m & 2.75/5 & 13.25\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

and it looks like this: [My compiled picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmymI.png)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Unless you really hate your readers, don't try to make your table look like that

Comment: you might want to read http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

Comment: What is the difference between the two pictures that you are concerned about? At first glance the only obvious difference is the presence of the caption or title under the Table I heading (the part that reads "Curation Analysis..."). Is that right? Do you just want to add that heading or am I missing something else that's different between the two images?

Answer (score 0):

A first suggestion of working code to confront with yours:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{Curation analysis for \emph{Let it snow} levels 2 to 6}
  \label{tab:tab1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c||c|}
    \hline
    Level & Trial & Mod. & Time & Prop. & Tot.\\
    \hline
    2 & 478 & 2 & 1h 19m & 3/5 & 16\\
    3 & 408 & 1 & 1h 04m & 2/5 & 12\\
    4 & 400 & 2 & 1h 00m & 3/5 & 14\\
    5 & 7531 & 3 & 17h 52m & 2/5 & 6\\
    6 & 402 & 1 & 0h 50m & 3/5 & 11\\
    \hline
    av. & 1843 & 1.6 & 4h 25m & 2.4/5 & 11.8\\
    av2 & 422 & 1.5 & 1h 3m & 2.75/5 & 13.25\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should consider removing the figure and the center enviroment and use the table enviroment instead. You will achive the same result but in the right way. As far as the question, im unsure to what specifically you want, i assume you want caption underneath, in that case add the option labelsep=newline to the caption package as shown in the dokumentation http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf.